# jQuery custom function does not load as expected:

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```js
function getData() {
  switch ($("#template-name").text()) {
    case "#first-contact-en":
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
      alert("test en");
      break;
    case "#first-contact-de":
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
      alert("test de");
      break;
    case "#first-contact-fr":
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
      alert("test fr");
      break;
    default:
      alert('Default case');
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
  }
};

$("input").keyup(function() {
  var templateLang = $("#template-name").text();
  var genderSel = $("input[name=gender]:checked").val();
  var gender = "";
  var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
  var fixnumb = $("#fixnumb").val();
  var recallDate1 = $("#recalldate").val();
  var recallDay = recallDate1.substring(8, 10);
  var recallMonth = recallDate1.substring(5, 7);
  var recallYear = recallDate1.substring(0, 4);
  var recallDate = "" + recallDay + "/" + recallMonth + "/" + recallYear + "";
  if (genderSel == "male" && templateLang == "en") {
    gender = "Dear Mr. ";
  } else if (genderSel == "female" && templateLang == "en") {
    gender = "Dear Ms. ";
  } else if (genderSel == "male" && templateLang == "de") {
    gender = "Sehr geehrter Herr ";
  } else if (genderSel == "female" && templateLang == "de") {
    gender = "Sehr geehrte Frau ";
  } else {
    gender = "it went through here ";
  }
  intro = gender;
  getData();
});
```

```css
.template-content-wrapper {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.template-form {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  background: red;
}

.template-form tr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.email-template {
  float: left;
  background: #dadada;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 690px;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/script.js"></script>

<div class="template-content-wrapper">
  <div class="template-form">
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" id="template-name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gender:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="true">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fix Number:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fixnumber" id="fixnumb"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobile Number:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="mobilenumber"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Recall date:</td>
          <td><input type="date" name="recalldate" id="recalldate"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Between:</td>
          <td><input type="time" name="callbetween"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>And:</td>
          <td><input type="time" name="callbetween"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="email-template" contenteditable="true">

  </div>
</div>
```

The switch function does work. The alert messages are appearing. But the `getData()` function I created does not seem to get the variables. and put them in the `.email-template` `div`. instead of loading last name I get the following error: [object HTMLInputElement].

when I add `$(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");` at the end of the `keyup()` function it works as expected.

Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance for any reply.

Comment: where is the template-name contents updated with a language?  I don't see that part.  It also seems weird that the text of the field would have text like #first-content-en which would be visible to the user.  Something seems missing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I use another file where you click on a button which has this ID. And when you click on this button a new file is loaded into the .email-template div. the #first-content-en will be hidden. I use this to get this text and store it as a variable to use it on the switch function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're referring to a variable `lastname` which is pointing to an HTML element, the input element whose ID is `lastname`. You may try to remove the ID of that input, and get an error instead.

I tried to correct your code by passing the value of `lastname` to the function, and it worked fine. Refer to the below snippet:

```js
function getData(lastname) {
  switch ($("#template-name").text()) {
    case "#first-contact-en":
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
      alert("test en");
      break;
    case "#first-contact-de":
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
      alert("test de");
      break;
    case "#first-contact-fr":
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
      alert("test fr");
      break;
    default:
      alert('Default case');
      $(".email-template").html("" + intro + lastname + "");
  }
};

$("input").keyup(function() {
  var templateLang = $("#template-name").text();
  var genderSel = $("input[name=gender]:checked").val();
  var gender = "";
  var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
  var fixnumb = $("#fixnumb").val();
  var recallDate1 = $("#recalldate").val();
  var recallDay = recallDate1.substring(8, 10);
  var recallMonth = recallDate1.substring(5, 7);
  var recallYear = recallDate1.substring(0, 4);
  var recallDate = "" + recallDay + "/" + recallMonth + "/" + recallYear + "";
  if (genderSel == "male" && templateLang == "en") {
    gender = "Dear Mr. ";
  } else if (genderSel == "female" && templateLang == "en") {
    gender = "Dear Ms. ";
  } else if (genderSel == "male" && templateLang == "de") {
    gender = "Sehr geehrter Herr ";
  } else if (genderSel == "female" && templateLang == "de") {
    gender = "Sehr geehrte Frau ";
  } else {
    gender = "it went through here ";
  }
  intro = gender;
  getData(lastname);
});
```

```css
.template-content-wrapper {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.template-form {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  background: red;
}

.template-form tr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.email-template {
  float: left;
  background: #dadada;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 690px;
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/script.js"></script>

<div class="template-content-wrapper">
  <div class="template-form">
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" id="template-name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gender:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="true">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fix Number:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fixnumber" id="fixnumb"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobile Number:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="mobilenumber"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Recall date:</td>
          <td><input type="date" name="recalldate" id="recalldate"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Between:</td>
          <td><input type="time" name="callbetween"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>And:</td>
          <td><input type="time" name="callbetween"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="email-template" contenteditable="true">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it :)

Comment: @SergeInácio Ideally you should be passing both `intro` and `lastname` as params to `getData()` function. Currently you are directly assigning value to `intro` variable inside your keyup handler. So its setting the value to a global variable (if no such variable exists, it will create one) and that's why its accessible in `getData()`. Whereas you are declaring `var lastname` which is creating a local variable inside keyup handler and hence its not accessible in the `getData()`.